# Django не успевает за запросами?

Tags: python, django, многопоточность, requests

На вьюхе есть код, который проверяет, есть ли такая запись в базе данных, если есть, то обновляет, если нет, то создает.

```
def create_or_update(model, serializer):
    validated_data = serializer.validated_data
    sel = validated_data['sel']
    model.objects.update_or_create(sel=sel, defaults=validated_data)
```

Также есть обычная функция request запроса, если его выполнять в одном потоке, то все работает нормально. Но если его выполнять в нескольких потоках, то джанго создает 2 одинаковых записи

```
def send_request(host, port, requests_count):
    .........
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

for i in range(2):
    th = Thread(target=send_request, args=(host, port, requests_count))
    th.start()
```

Это нормально или джанго не успевает обработать 2 одновременных запроса?

Comment: Как раз в том и дело, что отлично успевает. Два запроса одновременно проверяют наличие записи, одновременно узнают, что записи нет, и одновременно создают запись. И это ожидаемое поведение, в [документации update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) написано что так и должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Как раз в том и дело, что отлично успевает. Два запроса одновременно проверяют наличие записи, одновременно узнают, что записи нет, и одновременно создают запись. И это ожидаемое поведение, в документации update_or_create написано что так и должно быть –
@andreymal